# Как разобраться со словами "Не принято" и "Неприемлемо"

Tags: орфография

Неприемлемо - наречие, пишется с НЕ только слитно и никогда раздельно? Хотя слово "приемлемо" - есть.

(Так) не принято - краткое причастие? НЕ пишется только раздельно? А почему это слово нельзя считать наречием и НЕ писать слитно?

Answer (score 3):

```
  Неприемлемо - наречие, пишется с НЕ только слитно и никогда 
  раздельно?
```

Решение неприемлемо-(каково?)-краткое прилагательное, пишется слитно, как и полное - неприемлемый. Утверждается, что оно неприемлемое.

Ну, знаете, решение это никак не приемлемо. - отрицается, что приемлемо, отрицание усиливается отрицательным наречием никак.

-Думаю, выглядит всё вполне приемлемо.-Ну что Вы, выглядит это далеко не приемлемо.-наречие отрицает, что выглядит приемлемо. Раздельно.

```
(Так) не принято - краткое причастие? НЕ пишется только раздельно? 
   А       почему       это слово нельзя считать наречием и НЕ писать слитно?
```

Решение каково?что сделано?-не принято.- не с кратким причастием пишется всегда раздельно.

У нас не принято так делать-краткое прилагательное, перешедшее в предикативное наречие (категория состояния в роли сказуемого)-раздельно.

Answer (score 2):

Нельзя краткое причастие или краткое прилагательное "считать" наречием, но они иногда могут совпадать по форме. **Наличие всех форм проверяется по словарю.**

НЕПРИЕМЛЕМЫЙ,  Такой, который нельзя принять, с которым нельзя согласиться; недопустимый. Неприемлемое решение. Ваше решение неприемлемо. Краткое прилагательное, нет наречия "неприемлемо.  Написание слитное, отрицательную конструкцию сложно образовать.

ПРИЕМЛЕМЫЙ,  Такой, который можно принять, с которым можно согласиться. П. проект.  Эта задача вполне приемлема. Приемлемо, нареч. Всё выглядит (как) приемлемо. Наречие "приемлемо" существует.

Принять - принятый - принят (краткое причастие), наречие от причастия не образуется. Но в некоторых случаях причастие переходит в прилагательное и от него образуется наречие, например: убитый (подавленный) вид, выглядеть (как) убито.